# How can I connect multiple if statements when using regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code for a password verification process with at least one lowercase, one uppercase and one number.

```
import re
password=raw_input('Enter the Password')

x= (re.findall(r'[a-z]',password))
if len(x)==0:
   print " at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed"
else:
   #(what should i write here to connect this to the next step?)

y=(re.findall(r'[A-Z',password))
if len(y)==0:
   print "at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed"
else:
   #(what should i write here?)

z=(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password))

if len(z)==0:
   print "at least one '0-9' requirment not completed"
else:
  print ' Good password!'
```

My desire is to let Python run in such a way that if `x` is not 0, then go ahead and verify if `y` is equal to 0. If not, verify `z` is not equal to 0. If not, tell the user that the password is good.

Comment: There's a duplicate of the more general version of this, but in short: wrap it all in a function, and `return` early from that function for the `len(x) = 0` parts. Then you don't need an `else` clause, and you just step through each `if-statement` or return early. (You can return `False`, or `True` at the very end, and your function is then simply `validate_password`.

Comment: An alternative if an `if-elif-elif-...` chain, and move the `findall` assignments into that chain directly: `elif len(re.findall(r'[A-Z', password)) == 0:` etc.

Comment: Basically, your else clause should be cascading:

Comment: Last note: this is horrible way to validate a password. "Password1" is a good password here, while "some lengthy random phrase that is hard to guess" is invalid. Also, `raw_input` echos the password: brrr. [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html).

Comment: @Evert        I know this is not a good way to validate ;)   Thanks for your input. I tried ur alternative if method if-elif-elif.. but can't make it work.. can u shed a bit more light in my eyes. Thanks

Comment: The if-elif chain is the same as engineer14's second suggestion or Psidom's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if-elif` statement:

```
import re
password=raw_input('Enter the Password')

if len(re.findall(r'[a-z]',password))==0:
    print " at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed"
elif len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',password)) == 0:
    print "at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed"
elif len(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password)) == 0:
    print "at least one '0-9' requirment not completed"
else:
    print ' Good password!'
```

A demo:

```
Enter the Password  Axa3
 Good password!

Enter the Password  aa3
at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed

Enter the Password  A3443E
 at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
password=raw_input('Enter the Password: ')
problems = []

x = re.findall(r'[a-z]',password)
if not x:
   problems.append("at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed")

y = re.findall(r'[A-Z]',password)
if not y:
   problems.append("at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed")

z = re.findall(r'[0-9]',password)
if not z:
   problems.append("at least one '0-9' requirment not completed")

if problems:
    print ' There were some problems with your password: ' + ', '.join(problems)
else:
    print ' Good password!'
```

Comment: @gurkha_dawg FYI: "It is not working" is supremely unhelpful. Is it not working because it does not give the correct result, or because it crashes?

Comment: @gurkha_dawg I've fixed `findall(r'[A-Z',password)` - it should be `findall(r'[A-Z]',password)`, otherwise it raises `unexpected end of regular expression`. This error is in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it only using string methods!

```
p = raw_input('enter password')
if p.islower() or p.isupper() or not any(c.isdigit() for c in p):
    print('bad password')
```

Comment: What about the information on why it was a bad password?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your else clause is just going to be the next statement, like so. You pretty much wrote it, all you have to do is indent each of the check.

```
    import re
    password=raw_input('Enter the Password')

    x= (re.findall(r'[a-z]',password))
    if len(x)==0:
         print " at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed"
    else:
        y=(re.findall(r'[A-Z',password))
        if len(y)==0:
             print "at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed"
        else:
            z=(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password))

            if len(z)==0:
                 print "at least one '0-9' requirment not completed"
            else:
                print ' Good password!'
```

option 2:

```
    import re
    password=raw_input('Enter the Password')

    if not (re.findall(r'[a-z]',password)):
         print " at least one 'a-z' requirment not completed"
    elif not (re.findall(r'[A-Z',password)):
        print "at least one 'A-Z' requirement not completed"
    elif not (re.findall(r'[0-9]',password)):
        print "at least one '0-9' requirment not completed"
    else:
        print ' Good password!'
```